# Django DetailView raise 404 not found error in real server

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I use Django 2.1, Python 3.5 and MySql (MariaDB 10).
All things in localhost is correct, but in real server, DetailView raise 404 error. Please help me.
My view code is:

```
class Blog_detail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

and my url pattern is:

```
path('blog/<str:slug>/', views.Blog_detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

My connection is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        # 'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'charset': 'utf8'
        },
    }
```

DetailView result only in Latin URI work correctly, but in utf-8 or Unicode URI raise 404 error.

Comment: Can you give some hints regarding your live server setup? Are you using nginx? 
Also, can you add some logging on your server environment so you can figure out if the request reaches the view or not? (does it fail to resolve the url, or does it fail to fetch the object?)

Comment: Do you actually have a post with that slug in your real database?

Comment: @Geekfish my server is nginx. And it fail to fetch the object.

Comment: @Daniel-roseman Yes of course, also I change that slug record to latin text and work correctly ! only in utf8 this error shown.

Comment: Can you add some logging so that you can see what the `slug` parameter received by the view is?
Are your database settings identical on the server and locally?

Something kind of related, you may want to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` in mysql, as, weirdly `utf8` doesn't support Unicode characters.

Comment: @Geekfish I done it, but I got no answer. And my database settings are identical on the server and locally. Also I tested the utf8mb4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. I found the answer to my question. I can use the following code:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'
    
    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Post, slug=uri_to_iri(slug))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FBV instead of CBV.

Use the following code:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.utils.encoding import uri_to_iri 

def blog_detail(request, slug):
    post= get_object_or_404(Post, slug=uri_to_iri(slug))
```

Comment: Thanks,it's worked. But I should only use Class based view.